# Не могу дорешить задачу

Tags: python, ооп

**Задача**

https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-sorted-lists/

Вам даны главы двух отсортированных связанных списков list1 и list2.

Объедините два списка в один отсортированный список. Список должен быть составлен путем соединения узлов первых двух списков.

Возвращает заголовок объединенного связанного списка.

Пример 1:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Ввод: list1 = [1,2,4], list2 = [1,3,4]


Вывод: [1,1,2,3,4,4]
```

Пример 2:

```
Ввод: list1 = [], list2 = []
Вывод: []
```

**Мой код**

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
new_list_1 = []
new_list_2 = []
class Solution(object):
    def mergeTwoLists(self, list1, list2):
        """
        :type list1: Optional[ListNode]
        :type list2: Optional[ListNode]
        :rtype: Optional[ListNode]
        """
        if list1 != None:
            for key,value in list1.__dict__.items():
                if isinstance(value, int):
                    new_list_1.append(value)
                else:
                    return self.mergeTwoLists(value, list2)
        if list2 != None:
            for key,value in list2.__dict__.items():
                if isinstance(value, int):
                    new_list_2.append(value)
                else:
                    return self.mergeTwoLists(list1, value)
        total_list = new_list_1 + new_list_2
        total_list.sort()
```

**Проблема**

*Задача решена* в *total_list* лежит *ответ*, как мне превратить *total_list* в тип ListNode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то вы не то вообще делаете. Задача на слияние решается применением алгоритма merge (из mergesort).

Многословно получилось:

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution:
    def mergeTwoLists(self, list1: Optional[ListNode], list2: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        res = ListNode()
        head = res
        t = None
        while list1 and list2:
            if list1.val <= list2.val:
                res.val = list1.val
                list1 = list1.next
            else:    
                res.val = list2.val
                list2 = list2.next
            res.next = ListNode()
            t = res
            res = res.next
        while list1:
            res.val = list1.val
            list1 = list1.next
            res.next = ListNode()
            t = res
            res = res.next
        while list2:
            res.val = list2.val
            list2 = list2.next
            res.next = ListNode()
            t = res
            res = res.next
        if t:
            t.next = None    
        else:
            head = None
        return head
```

Comment: Благодарю вас, я хотел превратить два списка в обычные, отсортировать, а после превратить обратно в ListNode. Для этого я использовал рекурсия, чтобы вытащить оттуда значения. Потом превратить обратно в тип ListNode. Я думаю, что мой способ реален в исполнении, но придётся подумать. Просто мне надо как-то сесть и по изучать стандартные алгоритмы(знаю только Евклида).